# Angular NgRx. Can I get in some way an argument from ofType parameter?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

So I have this effect:

```
filterArticles$ = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(filterArticles),
            switchMap(() =>
                from(this.cardService.getFilteredCardInfo('')).pipe(
                    map(articles => loadArticlesSuccess({ articles: articles })),
                    catchError(error => of(loadArticlesFailure({ error })))
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

action `filterArticles` has an argument `keywords`, is there any way to get it and pass as a parameter in the method `getFilteredCardInfo`?
My goal is to filter articles in an array by keywords.

Answer (score 1):

ofType is simply short end for a filter. This means the data it receives is passed on, just like filter.

So:

```
filterArticles$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(filterArticles),
        switchMap((keywords) =>
            from(this.cardService.getFilteredCardInfo(keywords)).pipe(
                map(articles => loadArticlesSuccess({ articles: articles })),
                catchError(error => of(loadArticlesFailure({ error })))
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Also note that the from() is superfluous, this would make things even clearer:

```
filterArticles$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(filterArticles),
        switchMap(this.cardService.getFilteredCardInfo),
        map(articles => loadArticlesSuccess({ articles: articles })),
        catchError(error => of(loadArticlesFailure({ error })))
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It seems to work.

Comment: If the answer did help you please accept it @YaroslavOmelianenko